# PREDICATE( name, arity )

Tags: visual-studio-2008, swi-prolog

Suppose I have the program below:

```
#include files

PREDICATE( add, 3 )
{
    return A3 = (long)A1 + (long)A2;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    PlEngine e( argv[0] );
    PlCall( "consult('myFile.pl')" );
    PL_halt( PL_toplevel() ? 0 : 1 );
}
```

When I compile it, it links Prolog and C++ and then launches the Prolog command prompt.

All I have in myFile.pl is

```
:- use_module( library(shlib) ).
```

When I type listing at the Prolog prompt, I get

```
Foreign: add/3
```

My question is how do I use the result of some other subroutine, say a class, in my foreign predicate add?  Let's say I have a class somewhere in my program that calculates some x and y.  Obviously x and y would be private or protected members of that class' header file.  How do I use x and y in my add predicate?  For instance, if I wanted to return the sum of x and y and first and second arguments of add?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If it is necessary to call external code on private members of classes, then  those classes need to call external code. The code must be "C" not "C++" compiled, in order to preserve symbol names.

In this case the class with the private x,y would have to call add(x,y) and get the result. The class needs a method to tell it to call the external `add/3`.

```
 extern "C" int add(int x, int y);
 class Priv{
        int x,y;
      public:
        int privadd(void){
            return add(x,y);
        }
   };
```